# AttributeError: 'spacy.pipeline.ner.EntityRecognizer' object has no attribute 'add_pipe'

Tags: nlp

Why does the following code throw the error that the `add_pipe` attribute is no defined?

```py
if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
    ner.add_pipe(ner , last = True)
    for _, annotation in train_data:
      for ent in annotation['entities']:
        ner.add_label(ent[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

To add pipeline components to spacy you have to add them to the loaded model (`nlp`) and not a single component (like `ner`).

```
if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names: 
    ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner') 
    nlp.add_pipe(ner, last = True)  # replaced ner by nlp here
    for _, annotation in train_data: 
        for ent in annotation['entities']: 
            ner.add_label(ent[2])
```